# Sitecore Contacts – Create and save contacts to and from xDB (MongoDB)

Tags: xdb, upgrade, mongodb

When making our site in Sitecore 8.2 we have followed steps from this website

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/10/09/sitecore-contacts-create-and-save-contacts-directly-to-and-from-xdb-mongodb/

but while upgrading it to Sitecore 9.3, I am not able to use many functionality like LockAttemptResult, LockAttemptStatus are deprecated.

Cannot initiate `contactRepository` and `ContactManager` with these:

```
ContactRepository contactRepository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepository;
ContactManager contactManager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
```

Anyone has better solution to perform and modify this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Sitecore StackExchange. For sitecore 9.3 you can take a look at the approach written in the sitecore `ContactManager` documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/contactmanager-reference.html:

```
var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;
```

It also contains details on modifying a contact with an ongoing session. I would suggest to try to rewrite your old code because `ContactRepository` is not recommended to be used, instead if you need to modify a contact you should use xConnect Client API https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/xconnect-client-api-overview.html